# Error:Execution failed for task , finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

> Error:Execution failed for task ':onyxenrollwizardsampleapp:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Here is my Gradle file. Kindly help me out

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.onyx_enroll_wizard_sample_app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.diamondfortress.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }

    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.diamondfortress.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.dft.android:onyx-enroll-wizard:4.1.3'
}
```

Comment: Please check above this error, There will be more description in error window and post it.

Comment: @Shvet They all are warnings and the search suggests that it can be ignored. Should I post them?

Comment: please change build tool version to 23.0.1 and sync it again.

Comment: @JonSnow Did once....and for your comment....did once again but the result is same.

Comment: use ./gradlew assemble --info and post the stacktrace

Comment: Facing the same issue did you get any answer...

Comment: @AshutoshSalodkar nops....i left that project

Comment: Is there any other error message before the mentioned error? Like I had error in manifest file.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Build menu - Clear Project, and Rebuild Project, It worked for me..

Comment: This worked for me, except for a small clarification, it is "Clean Project", not "Clear Project".

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" //Just change this from 23.0.2 to 23.0.1

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.onyx_enroll_wizard_sample_app"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()

maven {
    url 'http://nexus.diamondfortress.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
}

maven {
    url 'http://nexus.diamondfortress.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots'
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.1'
compile 'com.dft.android:onyx-enroll-wizard:4.1.3'
}
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Same here it doesn't fix mine too.

Comment: @Omkar can u put your gradle file?

Comment: My issue is resolved. After searching all around, I figure out that due to some reason my manifest file tags got changed. **I suggest recheck the manifest file tags.**

Answer (score 0):

This is due to incorrectly configured AndroidManifest.  For example, the

```
         package="com.mypackage.myname"
```

may be incorrect, or it doesn't match the applicationId in **build.gradle**:

```
        applicationId "com.mypackage.myname"
```

Make sure you fix those.

Comment: names are same, still facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens after updating. Next 2 steps may help:

From "Build" menu.

```
Build -> Clean Project

Build -> Rebuild Project
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that that sdk version 23 is installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

I caused this error because the code below

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

in the `AndroidMainfest.xml` file and i remove this code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

> In my case, it was module-info.java's fault.  IntelliJ couldn't find
> the module-info.java's because the path wasn't correct. In
> build.gradle, it was

```
 application {
    mainModule = 'it.unicam.cs.pa2122.TomaMatteo116781'
    mainClass = 'package.YourMain'
    }
```

> I changed it in:

```
  application {
    mainModule = 'it.unicam.cs'
    mainClass = 'package.YourMain'
    }
```