# Ionic (+cordova,android.sdk,gradlew) Execution failed for task <task_name>

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradlew

(my problem was related to ionic, and it is common problem here, it is caused by using cordova and android.sdk, so I am adding these flags too)

I had problem running [`ionic run android [-lc]`, `ionic build android`] (if you got it in ios or other commands, and it is solved by this answer - comment please)

> Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 
>   'C:\Android_SDK\build-tools\24.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value

To be honest, you can call it

> Execution failed for task .
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 
>   'C:\Android_SDK\build-tools\24.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit

Answer (score 0):

At the start you can try other, faster fixes:

- [Execution failed for task :processDebugResources [ Cordova / Ionic ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861905/execution-failed-for-task-processdebugresources-cordova-ionic) (actually it covers answer to mine, but there is lack of debugging and fixing deeper problems)
- [ionic build android failure - Execution failed for task processDebugResources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645900/ionic-build-android-failure-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugresources?rq=1)
- [Error:Execution failed for task , finished with non-zero exit value 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840001/errorexecution-failed-for-task-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1)

### Try to update cordova (and Ionic)

If you aren't using the ionic, remove `ionic` from command.

`npm update cordova ionic` or if it is globally `npm update -g cordova ionic`

### How to debug it:

Try to find the `gradlew`. 
(for Windows) `gradlew.bat`, (for Unix'ies) `gradlew` (dot something I guess - comment me please)

> *Ionic (Windows)*: `project_name/platforms/platform(android)/gradlew.bat` (example: `C:\workspace\Caparol\platforms\android\gradlew.bat`)

> *Other system/framework? Add an edit/comment.*

(I am using the git bash, I am not sure if that works in pure cmd on Windows, it should work in any Unix terminal)

Go to the `platform_name` directory, that contains your gradlew file.

Process `./gradlew_file assembleDebug --info` (example `./gradlew.bat assembleDebug --info`) or/and `./gradlew_file --info build clean` (example `./gradlew.bat --info build clean`)

In output you got more detailed information than using `--stack-trace` or `--info` or `--debug` in usual build command.

#### Invalid path

`C:\workspace\project_name\platforms\android\build\intermediates\assets\debug\www\dir\Zdj▒cia: error: Invalid directory name, unable to add.`

And fix not valid characters in path - dont use national characters.

Then - fix it in your project and `build/intermediates` folder. (or delete `build/intermediates`)

#### Lint error

You can get problems like

> Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:lint'.
>   Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.

for example I got:

> Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:lint'.

```
android {
  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }
}
```

Fix it to valid file_type syntax.

> More cases? Comment me please.