# Phonegap android build :processDebugResources

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I got recently this `FAILURE` when i try to export my app.
I am using latest tools and everything updated. I have found like 10 posts answers to this, which pointing to change version of sdk. 
I am trying to export via `phonegap build android`. I have tried to create new app from phonegap demo and everything worked out. After that i copied folder www from my app to that new app and then i got again the same error, what i have to search in my code?.

> Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/denishonchar/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/24.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Have you looked at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181901/ionic-cordova-android-sdk-gradlew-execution-failed-for-task-task-name ? This link also talks about special characters in file names : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861905/execution-failed-for-task-processdebugresources-cordova-ionic. That could be your issue since you said you copy/paste and you have this issue in a fresh project.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after research in the project files, there was one file which had strange name. My suggestion to other which will have this issue is the try copy files by files and check if `phonegap build os` works.